# Given N, find the smallest number A that A^A divisible by N

Tags: algorithm, math

This problem describes that :

**Given N, find the smallest number A that A^A divisible by N. (N<=1.000.000.000)**

E.g: N=9 , output A=3 (3^3 mod 9=0) ; given N=6 output A=6 (6^6 mod 6=0).

I calculate from 1 until I find number appropriate, but during I calculate variable (A^A) then data overflow. How can I find number A faster and no data overflow?

Comment: Solving this will require some math insight rather than coding help. Maybe think about the prime factors of N and how you can deduce A from them.

Comment: Thank you  so much, I will edit it soon.

Comment: Does `^` stand for **xor** (`3 ^ 3 == 0`) or for **raising into power** (`3 ^ 3 == 27`)?

Comment: If you are looking for *brute force* you can try *modular exponentiation*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation

Comment: @DmitryBychenko it would be exponentiation, since `A xor A` would be divisible by all `N`

Comment: Instead of checking if A^A is divisible by N, check if A mod N = 0, then if A is a perfect square, your answer is the square root of A. This avoids the overflow issue, but is not faster. I think this problem is trying to teach you something about solving modulos of very big numbers. There is a nice math property about a^b mod c that, makes it easy to solve such large products without having to deal with big numbers. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7gHx2StFi8

Comment: This job might turn out to be somewhat complicated. What @smac89 mentions is only valid if the `A` that you try, happens to solve the equation `A^A = 0 mod N`. However for some `N` there might not be an `A` and you may end up increasing `A` indefinitely without knowing where to stop. This problem probably happens to be a special case of  the [Discrete Logarithm Problem](https://www.brainkart.com/article/Discrete-Logarithms_8433/). I believe this question is more suitable for the [Math branch of Stack Excahange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discrete-logarithms).

Answer (score 1):

1. The prime factors of `A` should be the same as the prime factors of `N`. Having less factors means `A^A % N !=0`, having more factors is pointless since we're looking for the smallest `A`.
2. Let `N` have prime factorization `2^a * 3^b * 5^c ...`. The exponent array for `N` would be `expo_N = [a,b,c...]`
3. Let `y = product of prime factors of N`. The exponent array for `y` would be `[1,1,1...]`. The exponent array of `y^y` will be `expo_y = [y,y,y...]`.
4. For `y^y` to be divisible by `N`, `expo_y[i] >= expo_N[i] for i in range(length(expo_N))`.
5. Let `x = max(a,b,c...)`. Now, using the points mentioned above, `y >= x` to satisfy point #4. If `y>=x`, you have the answer. Else, keep on multiplying `y` by `2` while `y < x`.

This approach doesn't involve actually exponentiating the numbers, so it would timeout or error out. Factorization of `N` can be done in `O(sqrt(N))`, the remaining operations will be done in `O(logN)` number of prime factors.

###### Example 1: `N = 9`

1. `expo_N = [3: 2] (since N = 3^2)`
2. `y = 3, expo_y = [3: 3]`
3. Since `expo_y[i] >= expo_N[i] for all i`, answer is `A = y = 3`

###### Example 2: `N = 6`

1. `expo_N = [2: 1, 3: 1]`
2. `y = 6, expo_y = [2: 6, 3: 6]`
3. Since `expo_y[i] >= expo_N[i] for all i`, answer is `A = y = 6`

###### Example 3: `N = 384`

1. `expo_N = [2: 7, 3: 1]`
2. `y = 6, expo_y = [2: 6, 3: 6]`
3. `expo_N[2] = 7`, so we multiply `y` by `2`
4. `y = 2*y = 12, expo_y = [2: 24, 3: 12]`
5. Now the condition is satisfied, so the answer is `A = y = 12`

Comment: @kcsquared wouldn't 6 be the correct answer?

Comment: Yes, thanks, N=81 should indeed return 6. I still think step 5 doesn’t always work; for N=9^9, you’ll start with y=3, so multiplying by 2 repeatedly will get you to 12 as the output

Comment: @Spektre why do we need perfect squares?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur aaaah that  is `A^A` not `A*A` :) my bad ignore previous comments